# Fetch data from user logged in with php into html table

Tags: php, html

I have the files shown below:

index.html this one is the log in html form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login">
            <h1>Welcome! Let's Login</h1>
            <form action="authenticate.php" method="post">
                <label for="username">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
                <label for="password">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
                <a href="register.html">No account? Sign up!</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

authenticate.php this one is the connection with the database to authenticate the user and log him to the profile

```
<?php
session_start();
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'wdb';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    .
    exit('Please fill both the username and password fields!');
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT email, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();


   

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            header('Location: hometest.php');
        } else {
            // Incorrect password
            //echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
            header("Refresh:0; url=index.html");
            echo"<script>alert('Incorrect username and/or password!');</script>";
            die;
        }
    } else {
        // Incorrect username
        //echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
        header("Refresh:0; url=index.html");
        echo"<script>alert('Incorrect username and/or password!');</script>";
        die;
    }


    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

and hometest.php and this one is the profile for the user that logs in successfully

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link href="stylehometest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

    <body class="loggedin">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <header>
        
      <label for="check">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" id="sidebar_btn"></i>
      </label>

      <div class="left_area">
        <h3>WebSite<span>Title</span></h3>
      </div>

      <div class="right_area">
        <a href="logout.php" class="logout_btn"> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a>
      </div>

    </header>
    
    <div class="sidebar">
      <center>
        <img src="logo.png" class="profile_image" alt="">
      </center>
      <a class="home" href="hometest.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><span>HomePage</span></a>
      
  

      <!---Button PROFILE--->
        
      <button type="submit" class="openbutton" onclick="openProfile()"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Your Profile</button>
      <div class= "form-popup2" id="Profilenfo">

        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container2">

          <h6 class="heading-small">User information</h6> 
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column"> 
              <label class="form-control-label" for="input-username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" id="input-username" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Username" value= <?=$_SESSION['name']?>>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="input-password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="input-password" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
                
            <div class="column">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="input-email">Email address</label>
              <input type="text" id="input-email" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Email" value= <?=$_SESSION['email']?>>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="input-confirmpassword"> Verify Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="input-confrimpassword" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Confirm password"> 
            </div>

          </div>

          <hr>
          <h6 class="heading-small" id="aboutMe">About me</h6>

          <div class="row">

            <div class="column">
              <h6 id="lastupload">Latest Upload:</h6>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>Cell A</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              
            </div>

            <div class="column">
              <h6 id="numberofrecords">Number of records:</h6>
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Cell B</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              
            </div>

          </div>
        
        </form>

      </div>


      <!--Button UPLOAD FILE-->
        
      <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>Upload Data</button>
      <div class="form-popup" id="UploadForm">
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
          <h1>Upload a file</h1>

          <label for="email"><b>Choose File:</b></label>
          <input type="file" name="UploadFile" required>

          <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Upload&excl;</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Ακύρωση</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <!---<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span>Your Profile</span></a>--->
    </div>
    

        <div class="content">
            <p>Welcome back, <?=$_SESSION['name']?>!</p>
        </div>

    <script>
      function openForm() {
        closeProfile();
        document.getElementById("UploadForm").style.display = "block";
      }

      function closeForm() {
        document.getElementById("UploadForm").style.display = "none";
      } 

      function openProfile() {
        closeForm();
        document.getElementById("Profilenfo").style.display = "block";
      }

      function closeProfile(){
        document.getElementById("Profilenfo").style.display = "none";
      }
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to fetch a value with column name: number_of_records from a table called accounts from my database into the Cell B of the table in the hometest.php page. I can't figure out how to get the record for the user logged in every time...

Any help would be much appreciated, since I'm new to PHP, HTML and CSS and still trying to figure things out.

The table from which I want to retrieve the value looks like:
name of the table: accounts

| id | username | password | email | number_of_records |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 123 | test@test.com | 3 |

The value number_of_records updates itself with a trigger, every time a user uploads a file to the table:

name of table: file

| fileID | date | userN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-28 23:49:56 | test |

I added the following parts of code in the hometest.php file and it works...maybe it's not the optimal solution...any comments and suggestions are welcome!

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
}
else{

 $user = 'root';
 $password = ''; 
  
 
 $database = 'db'; 
 
 $servername='localhost';
 $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $user, 
                $password, $database);
  
 if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . 
    $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. 
    $mysqli->connect_error);
}
  
 $sql = "SELECT number_of_records FROM accounts where username=? ";
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['name']);
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();   
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link href="stylehometest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

    <body class="loggedin">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <header>
        
      <label for="check">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" id="sidebar_btn"></i>
      </label>

      <div class="left_area">
        <h3>WebSite<span>Title</span></h3>
      </div>

      <div class="right_area">
        <a href="logout.php" class="logout_btn"> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a>
      </div>

    </header>
    
    <div class="sidebar">
      <center>
        <img src="logo.png" class="profile_image" alt="">
      </center>
      <a class="home" href="hometest.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><span>HomePage</span></a>
      
  

      <!---Button PROFILE--->
        
      <button type="submit" class="openbutton" onclick="openProfile()"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Your Profile</button>
      <div class= "form-popup2" id="Profilenfo">

        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container2">

          <h6 class="heading-small">User information</h6> 
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column"> 
              <label class="form-control-label" for="input-username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" id="input-username" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Username" value= <?=$_SESSION['name']?>>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="input-password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="input-password" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
                
            <div class="column">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="input-email">Email address</label>
              <input type="text" id="input-email" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Email" value= <?=$_SESSION['email']?>>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
              <label class="form-control-label" for="input-confirmpassword"> Verify Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="input-confrimpassword" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Confirm password"> 
            </div>

          </div>

          <hr>
          <h6 class="heading-small" id="aboutMe">About me</h6>

          <div class="row">

            <div class="column">
              <h6 id="lastupload">Latest Upload:</h6>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>Cell A</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              
            </div>

            <div class="column">
              <h6 id="numberofrecords">Number of records:</h6>
                <table>
                <?php 
                      while($user = $result->fetch_assoc())
                      {
                    ?>  
                  <tr>  
                    <td><?php echo $user['number_of_records'];?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                      }
                  ?>
                </table>
              
            </div>

          </div>
        
        </form>

      </div>


      <!--Button UPLOAD FILE-->
        
      <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>Upload Data</button>
      <div class="form-popup" id="UploadForm">
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
          <h1>Upload a file</h1>

          <label for="email"><b>Επιλογή αρχείου:</b></label>
          <input type="file" name="UploadFile" required>

          <label for="psw"><b>Κωδικός Πρόσβασης</b></label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Μεταφόρτωση&excl;</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Ακύρωση</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  
    </div>
    

        <div class="content">
            <p>Welcome back, <?=$_SESSION['name']?>!</p>
        </div>

    <script>
      function openForm() {
        closeProfile();
        document.getElementById("UploadForm").style.display = "block";
      }

      function closeForm() {
        document.getElementById("UploadForm").style.display = "none";
      } 

      function openProfile() {
        closeForm();
        document.getElementById("Profilenfo").style.display = "block";
      }

      function closeProfile(){
        document.getElementById("Profilenfo").style.display = "none";
      }
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can't really help you with any specifics without seeing the schema of the table you want to fetch data from. Normally, you store the user id in the session when the user logs in and then have a `user_id`-column in the other tables with the id of the user each record belongs to. Then you just do a SELECT with a `WHERE user_id = ?` on the tables you want to fetch records belonging to the user.

Comment: Who wrote the code that you posted? It seems to me that if you wrote that code you should also be able to figure out the answer to your question... 
Are you following a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: I added explanation about the tables I have..Thank you for the response!
@MagnusEriksson

Comment: The authanticate.php file is from a tutorial yes. @Erik

Comment: You should go through that code line by line and study what it actually does. It's usually a bad idea just top copy/paste and use code you find online if you don't understand it. since you won't have a chance of debugging it, in case something happens. It can also open you up for some serious security issues. Specially if we talk user authentication and such.

Comment: You seem to define the SQL connection details (password, etc.) as PHP variables but you don't unset these variables at any time. This is a security risk, and can very easily give access to your SQL.